# Need to read a value using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript that can read the value of this:

```
<div id="timer" >07.45</div>
```

,it's a timer and it counts from 20 seconds, it counts down in seconds and miliseconds , so how can I get let's say 07.45 value to be shown!
   This is what I tried but it doesn't work, it shows undefined

```
<div id="timer">07.45</div>    
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("timer").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The format here is that of a question and answer site, and in order for a question to be valid we need to know what it is your trying to do(check), what your end result should be(check), and what you have tried(please add). Your question could use a bit better formatting as well!

Comment: what do you mean "I need a javascript that can read the value of this" ? don't you know how to do a simple "document.getElementById('timer')"

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the effort the OP put into researching / trying is too low to be acceptable

Comment: Generally speaking, `div` elements don't have `values`. You might want the `innerHtml` instead.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question,

you're having trouble with the reading of value.

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML;
}
```

You can also read some DOM documentation around the web. Hope can help.